# array return wrong value laravel

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, class, laravel

I make an ajax request and the response its an array of images, the problem is that i echo the value of the array and its the one that i want, but when the foreach ends and i see what have the array every value its changed by the last item of the array

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
    $auxImg->misc_id    = $y->misc_id;
            $auxImg->image      = $y->image;

    $aux[$i] = $auxImg;
    echo $aux[$i]->image.' ';
    //response of the array in the echo

    /* 5/maqueta.png - 5/ponto.png - 5/ciades.jpg - 5/35235.jpg */
    $i++;
}
echo var_dump($aux);


//response in the var_dump of the aux array
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#400 (2) {
    ["misc_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["image"]=>
    string(11) "5/35235.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#400 (2) {
    ["misc_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["image"]=>
    string(11) "5/35235.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#400 (2) {
    ["misc_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["image"]=>
    string(11) "5/35235.jpg"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#400 (2) {
    ["misc_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["image"]=>
    string(11) "5/35235.jpg"
  }
}
```

i really cant understand why this happend, that is the only time i use $aux var please help

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `$auxImg` is all the time the same object, so in each step you modify this object and append it to array but because `$auxImg` is an object it's not copied.

You should add

```
$auxImg = new stdClass();
```

or

```
$auxImg = clone $auxImg;
```

(depending what code you use before loop)

after:

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
```

to get expected result.

Comment: thank you it did work, but i still dont understand why it show distinct values on the loop and the same outside?

Comment: This is because objects in PHP are not copied, so inside loop when you assign value you see this value but after loop you will see the same value. You can compare this to: `$x = new stdClass(); $x->a = 5; echo $x->a; $y = $x; $y->a = 10; echo $y->a; echo $x->a;` When you want to copy object you need to use `clone`